# Activity Lifecycle and the stack of activities

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with the following screen scheme:

```
             |------> Activity1
MainActivity |------> Activity2
```

The application navigation only use startActivity() calls and the standard "back button" function.

Considering an Activity as `created` when its in between the `onCreate` and the `onDestroy` methods.

May I assume that when the activity1 or 2 is created then the MainActivity is created too?

Comment: Do the arrows represent screen transitions? If so, and assuming you can only reach them from MainActivity, then yes, an instance of MainActivity will be created and in memory while the user is at Activity1 or Activity2. (Unless something strange happens and the system needs to kill that instance of MainActivity to free up resources, but that seems unlikely.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no guarantee** that the `MainActivity` will still be alive when you have `Activity1/2` in the foreground. Definitely it will be created when the app starts since it is the only way to reach to `Activity1/2`.

Once the `MainActivity` is covered by another activity it will be in `Stop` state and can be killed by the system when resources is needed.

You can have some control over this behavior by specifying `android:noHistory="true/false"` in your activity definition, which by default set to `false`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when Activity1 or Activity2 is `created`, then by your definition MainActivity has also been `created`. So, if you are trying to access variables or methods from within MainActivity, then will be there.